# Condition for both roots be infinity

Tags: quadratics

For what value/s of constant 'p' for which the given quadratic have both roots as infinity.
$(2p^3-13p^2+27p-18)x^2 + (2p^2-9p+9)x +2p^2-7p+6=0$
Options are :-
$1) 3/2
2) 2
3) 3
4) /phi $

Since both roots are infinite then sum of the roots must be infinity. For this quadratic let alpha and beta be the roots then we say that 
Alpha + beta (sum of roots) = -(2p^2-9p+9)/(2p^3-13p^2+27p-18)
For the sum to be infinity 2p^3-13p^2+27p-18 must equal to zero. On solving the  equation 2p^3-13p^2+27p-18=0 we get p1 =3/2 p2=2 and p3 =3.
For p1 and p3 2p^2-9p+9 become zero. So correct option for this question may be 2 but answer in my book is given as option 3. Why this is so.. plz explain me.

Comment: What do you mean by root at infinity ?

Comment: Roots as infinity means value of both roots to be infinity ( I think so)

Comment: Is this $$(2p^3-13p^2+27p-18)x^2+(2p^2-9p+9)x+2p^2-7p+6=0$$?

Comment: Yes @ Dr. Sonnhard

Comment: See in my solution the convention that a root is at infinity iff its inverse is zero. Have you already studied derivatives ?

Comment: @Jean No sir .. I don't study derivatives right now.

Comment: For $p=2$, the equation is no longer quadratic but it has a root, $x=0$. For $p=3/2$, the $LHS$ reduces to $0$ so the equation has infinite roots, i.e. $x\in\Bbb R$. There is no root for $p=3$ since $0x+0y+3\ne0$ for all $x\in\Bbb R$.

Comment: @Shubham But the ans of this question is option 3 I.e P= 3

Comment: @Saket There are finite roots for $p=2,3/2$ which leaves only $(b),(d)$ as possible answers.

Comment: @Shubham Question is not asking for the number of roots but it is asking for the value of roots to be infinity.

Comment: @Jean For roots to be infinity, Can we say that the coffecient of X^2 and coefficient of X must be equal to zero and Constant term must not be equal to zero

Comment: By finite roots I meant roots that are not infinity.

Comment: It is equivalent to that (s system formed by the 2 first coefficients equal to 0), but using the change of variables $x=1/y$ which is - in my view - compulsory, because one cannot reason safely on "roots at infinity" at your level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using the term "infinite $x$", we are going to invert things by setting $x=\frac{1}{y}$. And say by definition that "$x$ infinite" means that its inverse $y$ is zero.

But we must be a little cautious. Let us, in the initial equation, 
$(2p^3-13p^2+27p-18)x^2 + (2p^2-9p+9)x +2p^2-7p+6=0$

replace first $x$ by $\frac{1}{y}$ :

$$\underbrace{(2p^3-13p^2+27p-18)}_A\tfrac{1}{y^2} + \underbrace{(2p^2-9p+9)}_B\tfrac{1}{y} +\underbrace{(2p^2-7p+6)}_C=0 \tag{1}$$

Reducing the LHS (Left Hand Side) to a same denominator $y^2$, this equation is converted into "numerator = 0" which means a quadratic equation in variable $y$ :

$$\underbrace{(2p^2-7p+6)}_Cy^2+\underbrace{(2p^2-9p+9)}_By+\underbrace{(2p^3-13p^2+27p-18)}_A=0 \tag{2}$$

(note that the order of coefficients has been reversed between (1) and (2)).

This equation $Cy^2+By+A=0$ has a double root in $0$ iff it is of the form $Cy^2=0$. Thus it is equivalent to say that  coefficients $B$ and $A$ are $0$, thus verify the system

$$\begin{cases}B&=&2p^3-13p^2+27p-18&=&0 &\ \ (b)\\
A&=&2p^2-9p+9&=&0 &\ \ (a)\end{cases}$$

It remains for you to solve the system (a) and (b) .

Hint : multiply (a) by $p$ and substract to (b) : you will get a quadratic in $p$....

Comment: For roots to be infinity, Can we say that the coffecient of X^2 and coefficient of X must be equal to zero and Constant term must not be equal to zero.

Comment: @Saket Let the quadratic equation be $ax^2+bx+c=0$. Divide by $x^2$ on both sides to get$$a+b/x+c/x^2=0$$Since $\infty$ is a double root, this equation must be of the form $k\cdot\frac1x\cdot\frac1x,k\in\Bbb R-\{0\}$. This means $a=b=0,c\ne0$.

Comment: How you write k.1/x.1/x  explain plz..

Comment: @saketkumar A quadratic with roots $p,q$ is written as $a(x-p)(x-q)$. The equation in $1/x$ has both roots $0$, so it will be written as $k(1/x-0)(1/x-0)$

Comment: I have modified my answer in order (using the simpler approach suggested by @Shubham Johri): no need in fac to use derivatives.

Comment: @Shubham I am the basic learner of this chapter so can you explain me why you have taken the  roots to be zero then how you say that .. a = B = 0 and c not equal to zero

Comment: The essential thing : understand that the change of variable $x=\frac{1}{y}$ reverses the order of coefficients the quadratic in $x$ : $Cx^2+Bx+A=0$ becomes the following quaddratic in $y$ : $Ay^2+By+C=0$.

Comment: @saketkumar Refer to Jean's answer. They have substituted $x=1/y$ to obtain a quadratic equation in $y$. Since $\infty$ is a double root of the original equation, $y=0$ is a double root of the new equation (since $y=1/x$).